# Start calculation if BIN is complete (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, data-mining

I have a df with 250.000 rows, sorted by date. Another column called 'wind speed' consists of numbers from 1 to 25 in increments of 0.1, but is unsorted. Now I want to start a calculation with the 'Power' column if I have at least every integer number of 'wind speed' from 1 to 25 once. If I have multiple values for one number I want to built the average.
When I try an if clause, it checks the entire df and doesn't start the calculation when the BIN is complete. Then a new BIN should be searched for.

Does someoen have an idea how to do it?

This is a part of my df:

[image]

Comment: So, in conclusion, you want to group them together and calculate the average.

Comment: No I want to start a calculation when I have every integer number from 1 to 25 once. It could be in February but could also be in May... And then I want to start again from that point.

Comment: There is not a single integer in the wind speed column in the sample data. What kind of calculation is intended to be done?

Comment: With integer I mean every number with x.0. If I have every x.0 number from 0 to 25 I want to get a formula by doing a curve fit.